# Modifying a custom UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uislider

So I have a custom UISlider that I made with the following code:

```
UIImage *minImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_slider_fill.png"];
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_slider_empty.png"];
UIImage *tumbImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_slider_handle.png"];
minImage=[minImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
maxImage=[maxImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

[thresholdSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[thresholdSlider setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[thresholdSlider setThumbImage:tumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However this gives me a slider with an ugly square end on the left end.  I have an image that I want to use for the left cap, but I don't know how to programmatically set it as such.

This is the left end cap image I want to use:
[image]

This is the fill image I am using:
[image]

Comment: Can you include the images you're using, and the result? Typically you'd include the cap in your image, which would be covered by the left cap you're using in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can just use the end point and stretch it out rather than try to assign a dedicated left cap.